# Zimbra will not send email with Port 25 / 587 open

Tags: sendmail, zimbra

My VPS is hosted on DigitalOcean.
I managed to setup Zimbra, but when i want to send email, it does not send emails, but it receives emails from Webmails.

Checking from the Zimbra Admin I am seeing, this As an error

[image: error3.png]

So i have enabled ports 25 and 587 from firewall rules , So what and where am I getting it wrongly?